# How to install FlipDown.js library using Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I needed the FlipDown.js library for my project which uses Webpack.
I installed the library

```
npm i flipdown
```

But I don't know what should I do further to start working with the library.
How to import `flipdown.css` and `flipdown.js` to my `style.less` and `index.js` files, respectively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like [flipdown.js](https://github.com/PButcher/flipdown/blob/master/dist/flipdown.js) does not have any default exports defined.
You could try the following;

index.js

```
import 'flipdown';

const countdown = new FlipDown();
console.log(countdown); // Is this what you expect it to be?
```

As for the styles:

```
@import 'flipdown/dist/flipdown.css`;
```

Comment: Yes, flipdown.js hasn't got default exports. I tried your solution, but, unfortunately, it doesn't work. Thanks anyway for your answer

Comment: @AlexandrJärvi I made a pull request for this feature :)
https://github.com/PButcher/flipdown/pull/11

Comment: Try accessing it with `new window.FlipDown(...)`

Comment: Try accessing it with `new window.FlipDown(...)`